# Is it possible to have a USB to USB computer network?

Tags: usb, crossover

Was wondering if it was possible to have a USB to USB network for file transfer between two computers. As in there are two computers connected by a USB to USB connector and BOOM! Fast file transfer

Answer (score 3):

There are special cables with an "A" connector on both sides just for this purpose.  There is a piece of hardware between the two ends so each computer sees a USB device.  You cannot wire two host "A" ports directly to each other.

Comment: They're called "USB Networking Cables."

Answer (score 1):

You can't just use a simple cable with the relevant connector at each end, but you can get tables that have the needed electronics to behave as a network card in each machine. [This is one example](http://www.dealextreme.com/details.dx/sku.7768), search for "usb network cable" and you should find many more some of which will be available more locally to you. I'm not sure what top speed you'll get from them, but I expect it to be of the order of 25Mbyte/sec as that is where USB hard-drive adaptors tent to max out in my experience.

The other option is a pair of separate USB network adaptors like [these](http://www.dealextreme.com/details.dx/sku.10414) or [these](http://www.belkin.com/IWCatProductPage.process?Product_Id=281799). With 100Mbit adaptors you will max out at a bit over 10Mbye/sec, with gbit adaptors probably again at ~25Mbyte/sec. This will be more expensive, so if your machines have gbit NICs built in already (most modern machines do) you'd be better off just buying a small cheap gbit switch - reasonable quality 5-port gbit switches can be bought very cheaply these days.

USB2 is not going to be as fast as gbit ethernet, but should be around 2.5x the speed of 100mbit ethernet if you get good quality kit.

Answer (score 1):

Directly connecting two Host USB machines will generally cause a power short, which can damage the mother board.  Bluetooth or serial are much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, there's [networking over FireWire](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firewire#Networking_over_FireWire).

Comment: Unlike USB, you **can** just use a normal firewire cable to connect two PCs.